# C++ Converting string to int Write access violation _Left was 0xCCCCCCCC

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, data-structures, access-violation

I am a relatively new to C++ and trying to make a small strategy game but whilst trying to convert a string to and integer I get this error:

write access violation. _Left was 0xCCCCCCCC

And Visual Studio takes me to this code:

```
static void __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL assign(_Elem& _Left, const _Elem& _Right) 
_NOEXCEPT
{   // assign an element
    _Left = _Right;
}
```

Using break point i have figured out that the line of code which is causing the error is this:  CountriesFromFile[x].Area = stoi(Line);

CountriesFromFile[x].Area is an integer and Line is a string that i have read in from a file that
Line is definitely numeric as i have used cout to check.
Any help on how to fix this error would be much appreciated

### Update

Running CountriesFromFile[x].Area = 1; throws the same error.
I have also tested changing the value of x from 0 to 1 to 2 with no change

### Update2

I have messed around with my code for a bit and by removing the line of code i was having an error with i am now pretty sure it's the compiler as the error occurred somewhere else so i removed that line and the error occurred somewhere else. The error keeps on occurring when i try to make a variable = something

Comment: Perfect time to get to grips with your debugger, what does it tell you on inspecting `CountriesFromFile` just before `CountriesFromFile[x].Area = 1;`, should be fairly simple to trace back and figure out what's gone wrong :-)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: My crystal ball says `CountriesFromFile` is a vector and it's empty. Use `push_back().`

Comment: There's no question in there anywhere. We have no way to know what help you need. Do you know what a Write access violation is? If not, why don't you ask that? If so, why not show some analysis based on that? Do you know what `0xCCCCCCCC` suggests? If not, why not ask that? If so, why not show some analysis based on that?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: It's not the compiler, it's something you've done in your code, apparently repeatedly. We'd love to help if you decide to post an actual example of your code that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here, but "CountriesFromFile[x].Area = stoi(Line)" Looks fine.

0xCCCCCCCC is uninitialized memory so maybe check that you have intialized your "CountriesFromFile" array? And if so make sure that objects are actually being added to it at some point and it's not just empty.

Regards, an another c++ noob.